# tns preview not recognizing ios images for tabview tabItems added via App_Resources

Tags: ios, icons, nativescript, preview, tns

**Inbox and calendar images in App_Resources directory**

[image: inbox and calendar images in App_Resources directory]

They appear here and in the `platforms > ios > AppName > Resources` directory after running tns build.

**Inbox and calendar images in platforms Resources directory**

[image: inbox and calendar images in platforms Resources directory]

However when running app via tns preview, they do not sync to the phone/device

**Missing inbox and calendar icons in tns preview**

[image: missing inbox and calendar icons in tns preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Additions or deletions in the App_Resources directory are not sync to the preview app. When such changes are desired you will have to setup NativeScript and its dependencies on your machine (Android SDKs, Simulators, XCode etc.)

**Long answer:**

The `tns preview` command has some limitations to what changes can be synced and applied from your project. The general rule that you should have in mind is that any changes related to newly added files that cannot be converted to JS like image files, icons etc. will not be synced to the preview app. Such is the case with anything new you add to the App_Resources directory.

When running `tns preview` you should be prompted with warning for any files that will not be synced in the terminal. Also you can run `tns preview help` to see notes regarding this command and how to use it.

Comment: I already have everything set up on my local machine and other images in App_Resources, like the “home” icon on third tab, are showing correctly in tns preview. It seems like they should work in tns preview if others are already working.

Comment: The "Home" icon and others might be system icons that are by default included in the App Preview bundle but any additions you add will not be synced. If you already have the NativeScript development requirements installed on your local system simply use "tns run ios" "tns run android" rather than "tns preview". The preview option is more of a showcase to run NativeScript without the need of local installation, the "tns run" is much more powerful and should be used for bigger more customized projects.